# How to undersampling the majority class using pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I try to solve the data like below code,but I have not figured it out using groupy and udf ,and also find udf can not return dataframe.

Is there any way that could implement this by spark or some other method could handle unbalanced data

```html
ratio = 3
def balance_classes(grp):
    picked = grp.loc[grp.editorsSelection == True]
    n = round(picked.shape[0]*ratio)
    if n:        
        try:
            not_picked = grp.loc[grp.editorsSelection == False].sample(n)
        except: # In case, fewer than n comments with `editorsSelection == False`
            not_picked = grp.loc[grp.editorsSelection == False]
        balanced_grp = pd.concat([picked, not_picked])
        return balanced_grp
    else: # If no editor's pick for an article, dicard all comments from that article
        return None 

comments = comments.groupby('articleID').apply(balance_classes).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use this logic to undersample:

```
def resample(base_features,ratio,class_field,base_class):
    pos = base_features.filter(col(class_field)==base_class)
    neg = base_features.filter(col(class_field)!=base_class)
    total_pos = pos.count()
    total_neg = neg.count()
    fraction=float(total_pos*ratio)/float(total_neg)
    sampled = neg.sample(False,fraction)
    return sampled.union(pos)
```

base_feature is a spark dataframe that has the features. ratio is the desired ratio between positives and negatives class_field is the name of the column that holds the classes and base_class is the id of the class

Comment: Thanks your answer.
I am wondering assuming base_features is about 3M rows
and use this function. Is it a costly operation?

Comment: Depends on your cluster size :)